# How to suppress AutoDesk Inventor dialogs?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a server-side process that manipulates Inventor drawings (Inventor 2013).  I set:

```
inventorApp.UserInterfaceManager.UserInteractionDisabled = True
inventorApp.Visible = False
```

However, when I open a file that has, for example, a link to a file that is missing, a dialog is presented asking the user to skip/cancel.

```
inventorApp.Documents.Open(FileName, False)
```

How can I suppress all dialogs/interaction?  I am having trouble locating anything useful in the documentation.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you see if this does it?

```
 inventorApp.SilentOperation
```

When this property is set to true all dialogs should be supressed.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!  Didn't think to look for the word Silent.

Comment: Right, by default it's already set unless you specify that you want to handle the behavior.